# Plotting Anchored VWAP from 5 days ago to the current bar

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I have used published pine scripts to develope specific automation that I have in mind. I would like to plot Anchored VWAP starting from 5 days ago on 30 min chart (65 bars from the current bar). The program below does that, but when a new bar starts, the program recalculates using the new 65th bar from the new bar. this creates multiple lines in place of one VAVWAP line. Is there a way that I can fix the location of the start time and o  nly get one line on the chart?

```
 /// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © dogi60

//@version=5
indicator("Multi-Day VWAP Anchored on 30 min chart", "MDAVWAP30",overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count = 500)

src = input.source(ohlc4,'source')
        
htf=''
//function to calculate and store the vwap values 
f_avwap(src, date) =>
    float[]    array_sumSrc = array.new_float( date,na)
    float[]    array_sumVol = array.new_float( date,na)
    float[]    array_final = array.new_float( date,na)
    int[]    bar_finaltime = array.new_int( date,na)
    if date>0 and array.size(array_sumSrc)>0
        for i=date-1 to 0 
            sumSrc = src[i] * volume[i]
            sumVol = volume[i]
            array.set(array_sumSrc,i,sumSrc + sumSrc[1+i])
            array.set(array_sumVol,i,sumVol + sumVol[1+i])
            // sumSrc :=  sumSrc + sumSrc[1+i]
            // sumVol :=  sumVol + sumVol[1+i]
            finalVal=array.sum(array_sumSrc) / array.sum(array_sumVol)
            array.set(array_final,i,finalVal)
            array.set(bar_finaltime,i,time_close)
    [array_final,bar_finaltime]        

// get vwap starting from 5 days ago 
date = bar_index-bar_index[78]
[final_val,barTime]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,htf,f_avwap(src, date))


//plotting the vwap
if barstate.islast//confirmedhistory
    if array.size(final_val)>0
        for i=array.size(final_val)-1 to 0 
            line.new(bar_index[i+1],array.get(final_val,i),bar_index[i],array.get(final_val,i), color=color.red)   
            
     
            
//
```